# Is it possible to write a for loop to assign listeners to many button with the same function where final ints are used?

Tags: android, button, for-loop, android-intent, onclick

I am writing an android application and I have 8 buttons on one view that all have the same function, so I wanted to assign the same functionality to each button using a for loop rather than writing out 8 pieces of separate code. However, an issue arises when I want to use the the counter from the for loop within the onClick function to help fire an intent, here's the code:

```
//array of button ids
public int [] pickPlayers = { R.id.pick_player_1a, R.id.pick_player_2a, R.id.pick_player_3a, R.id.pick_player_4a, R.id.pick_player_1b, R.id.pick_player_2b, R.id.pick_player_3b, R.id.pick_player_4b};

//button to be used in for loop
public Button b;

//for loop to assign same functionality to buttons in pickPlayers array
for(int i = 0; i<pickPlayers.length; i++){
        b = (Button) findViewById(pickPlayers[i]);
        b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent getContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(getContactIntent, i);
            }
        });
    };
```

Hope that all makes sense, thanks to anyone who can help. :)

EDIT: This is the error I get: Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method

The for loop is in my oncreate method the variables and buttons are outside

Comment: You can also get those R.id.pick_player_xa inside the for loop, to save some effort. Read [this](http://goo.gl/on4WkI) and then pass the parameters as ("R.id.pick_player_"+ (i+1) + "a", "id", getPackageName()), and it will return the IDs of the buttons at runtime :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can't access variable in your inner classes if it's not declared as final. Simple workaround will be to create OnClickListener wrapper class.

```
private class MyListener implements Button.OnClickListener {
    int pos;
    public MyListener (int position) {
        pos = position;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent getContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(getContactIntent, pos);
    }
}
```

and then use it in you code like this

```
//for loop to assign same functionality to buttons in pickPlayers array
for(int i = 0; i<pickPlayers.length; i++){
    b = (Button) findViewById(pickPlayers[i]);
    b.setOnClickListener(new MyListener(i));
}
```

Also if your buttons are in some ViewGroup you can use [getChildAt](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) and [getChildCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildCount%28%29) to iterate them

```
ViewGroup parent;
// initialize the parent
int l = parent.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0 ; i < l ; i++) {
    Button button = parent.getChildAt(i);
}
```

Comment: Forgot to add I had to change extends to implements in your original answer

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code like that:

```
//for loop to assign same functionality to buttons in pickPlayers array
for(int i = 0; i<pickPlayers.length; i++){
        final int index = i;
        b = (Button) findViewById(pickPlayers[i]);
        b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent getContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(getContactIntent, index);
            }
        });
    };
```

This should do the job. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, the other method meant less code, so I used that, but now I can see what I was doing wrong through your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

If those buttons are decalred in XMl maybe you should set android:onClick listener to them through XML?

You have to define one method in your activity:

```
public void myHandler(View v) {
    // Your stuff...
}
```

And add

```
android:onClick="myHandler"
```

to all of them?

Thanks.

Comment: Got it working with the first solution, but will take a look at yours another time, not used this method before ':onclick'.